# errno 111 connection refused with python in ubuntu vmware

Tags: python, sockets, ubuntu

Hi I have a problem in my server- client connection 
I wrote the 2 codes on windows 10 and they worked perfectly. But when I tried to execute them on ubuntu in a VM I had this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "client3.py", line 9, in <module>
    sock.connect(('192.168.1.53', 1234))
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

the server code:

```
import threading
import SocketServer
import json
import base64

class ThreadedTCPRequestHandler(SocketServer.BaseRequestHandler):

    def handle(self):

        data = self.request.recv(327680)
        data = json.loads(data)
        cur_thread = threading.current_thread()
        JL= data['Jliste']
        for i in range(0,9) :
            cel = json.loads(JL[i])
            file_name = cel['name']
            img = base64.b64decode(cel['img'])
            with open(file_name,'wb') as _file:
                _file.write(img)
            print "image {} Received ".format(i)
        response = "images Received "
        print response
        self.request.sendall(response)

class ThreadedTCPServer(SocketServer.ThreadingMixIn, SocketServer.TCPServer):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":



        server = ThreadedTCPServer(("localhost", 1234), ThreadedTCPRequestHandler)


        # Start a thread with the server -- that thread will then start one
        # more thread for each request
        server_thread = threading.Thread(target=server.serve_forever)
        # Exit the server thread when the main thread terminates
        server_thread.daemon = True
        server_thread.start()
        print "Server loop running in thread:", server_thread.name
```

the client code:

```
import socket
import json


sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
sock.connect(('localhost', 1234))
try:

    def generate_names(count):
            return 'User.2.{}.jpg'.format(count)
    L = []
    for i in range(0,9):
            name = generate_names(i+1)
            fp = open(name,'rb')
            fp = fp.read()
            fp = fp.encode('base64')
            cel = {}
            cel['name'] = name
            cel['img'] = fp
            jcel = json.dumps(cel)
            L.append(jcel)
    data = {}
    data['Jliste'] = L
    s = json.dumps(data)
    sock.send(s)
    response = sock.recv(1024)
    print "Received: {}".format(response)
finally:
    sock.close()
```

the new error i get is:

```
Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 60900)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 596, in process_request_thread
    self.finish_request(request, client_address)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 331, in finish_request
    self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 652, in __init__
    self.handle()
  File "server.py", line 12, in handle
    data = json.loads(data)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 16913 (char 16912)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure why this works on Windows, but when I run your code on Ubuntu, your server just exits - just as it is supposed to. It prints "server loop running..." and then exits. As your thread is set to `server_thread.daemon=True`, the thread is killed as well. It does not even have time to initialise the socket.

If you change `server_thread.daemon=False` or add `sleep(600)` or something like that (you would of course an infinite loop) as the last statement in your main(), it starts listening to the socket and process requests - which is probably what you want.

Comment: thank you for your answer it solved the connection problem

Comment: Could you then please accept the answer, just in case someone else has a similar issue.

Comment: That error is related to json decoding. Your json decoder tries to decode json data but whatever it is trying to decode is not json formatted. You can catch the exception, print "data" if this error occurs, and then check from the printout what goes wrong with json syntax.